# Ansible Handlers not firing when change is made in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Hi guys i have a chain of handlers that I would like to fire only if an app is installed, but they don't seem to be firing.

Here is my roles/tills/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Install Dynamic Retail
  win_package:
    path: 'C:\Soft\common\Dynamic Retail 2009\Dynamic Retail 2009 Setup.msi'
    arguments: /QUIET
    creates_path: C:\Program Files\Dynamic Retail 2009 for Microsoft Dynamics NAV Client\Dynavics.DynamicRetail.dll
    notify: Copy Dynamics DLL
```

And here is my roles/tills/handlers/main.yml

```
---
- name: Copy Dynamics DLL
  win_copy:
    src: C:\Soft\common\Dynamic Retail 2009\Dynavics.DynamicRetail.dll
    dest: C:\Program Files\Dynamic Retail 2009 for Microsoft Dynamics NAV Client\Dynavics.DynamicRetail.dll
    remote_src: True
    notify: Copy Dynamics TLB

- name: Copy Dynamics TLB
  win_copy:
    src: C:\Soft\common\Dynamic Retail 2009\Dynavics.DynamicRetail.tlb
    dest: C:\Program Files\Dynamic Retail 2009 for Microsoft Dynamics NAV Client\Dynavics.DynamicRetail.tlb
    remote_src: True
    notify: Register Dynamic Retail DLLs

- name: Register Dynamic Retail DLLs
  win_command: C:\Soft\common\RegisterDR.bat
```

I'm sure i've missed something basic, but i can't seem to work out what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an indentation issue:

```
- name: Install Dynamic Retail
  win_package:
    path: 'C:\Soft\common\Dynamic Retail 2009\Dynamic Retail 2009 Setup.msi'
    arguments: /QUIET
    creates_path: C:\Program Files\Dynamic Retail 2009 for Microsoft Dynamics NAV Client\Dynavics.DynamicRetail.dll
  notify: Copy Dynamics DLL
```

('notify' should be inline with win_package, otherwise it is interpreted as a parameter of the win_package module, rather than the task that runs win_package)

Comment: That fixed it, I knew it was something arbitrary I was missing.
Thanks